# EditText in a tableRow how to fix 100%

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linearlayout with a table and a button, the table has EditText and TextView, my problem is with EditText, which is too small

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="300dip"
        android:layout_height="350dip"
        android:background="@drawable/background_resto"
    >
        
        <LinearLayout               
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity ="center"
            >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nameRegister"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="Nombre"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
                    />
            </TableRow>
            
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity ="center"   
            >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/registerName"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dip" 
                    />
            </TableRow>

            
        </TableLayout>
             <Button
                android:id="@+id/butRegister"
                android:layout_height="35dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enviar"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

I would like the EditText fix the 300dip that the first linearLayout, but I don't get it, what should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, add to `TableLayout` `stretchColumns` param

```
<TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:stretchColumns="1"
            >
```